# Calculate the area of a level in a Raster with points and buffer

Tags: lapply, terra

My primary goal is to calculate the area of natural soil based on a soil use raster within a 1Km buffer of my sites. I believe I’ve figured out how to calculate the buffer and extract the values within each one, but I’m unsure how to consolidate this information into a results table that includes the percentage for each point while maintaining its ID. I’ve attempted to prepare an example script of my workflow.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(terra)
    
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
CRS = crs(logo)
EXT = ext(logo)

p <- matrix(c(48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 85, 
              66, 42, 26, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 46, 38, 31, 
              22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 43, 28), ncol=2)

points <- vect(p, type="points")

buffers <- terra::buffer(points, width = 3)

Logo_extracted <- terra::extract(logo, buffers)
head(Logo_extracted, 20)


areas <- lapply(Logo_extracted, function(x){ table(x)})
areas
```

My intended output is something like this (my original raster has 2 categories: Natural and Anthropic).

```
ID  Blue  Red
1   0.25  0.52
2   0.34  0.33
3   0.78  0.1
4   0.41  0.28
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract` with `fun="table"`

Example data

```
library(terra)        
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
logo <- as.int(logo[[1]] > 200)
levels(logo) <- data.frame(id=c(0,1), class=c("anthropic", "natural"))
    
p <- matrix(c(48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 85, 
                  66, 42, 26, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 46, 38, 31, 
                  22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 43, 28), ncol=2)  
points <- vect(p, type="points")    
buffers <- terra::buffer(points, width = 3)
```

Solution

```
e <- extract(logo, buffers, fun="table")
head(e)
#  ID anthropic natural
#1  1        32       0
#2  2        22      10
#3  3        32       0
#4  4        32       0
#5  5        28       4
#6  6         6      26
```

Note that I am assuming that you have one raster layer with two classes. Not two layers, one for each class.